# How do I use a List<T> in Java?

Tags: java, generics

I'm working on a project using OpenCV, and there is a function which takes a List as a parameter.

```
Core.split(Mat m, List<Mat> mv);
```

I tried looking at documentation for List in Java however I'm confused as to how I would create a new list to use. I saw someone online say that list was just an Interface, but I'm not sure exactly what that means? (Sorry - Java isn't my first language)

What I was doing was -

```
private List<Mat> mList; 
private Mat listItem1; (etcetera) 

mList.add(listItem1)
```

The first part does not cause an error however when I try to `mList.add(listItem1)` this causes a NULL pointer exception. I'm assuming this is because I haven't initialised the List. I thought this would be a case of `mList = new List<Mat>();` however this gives me the error "Cannot instantiate the type List < Mat >"

Any help would be much appreciated - thanks! Sorry if this is a silly question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List` is an interface.  You need to use an implementation of `List`.  Try `ArrayList`.

```
mList = new ArrayList<Mat>();
```

Check the [JavaDoc for List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) for other implementations.

The reason you cannot instantiate `List` is because it is an [interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html).  It provides a contract with which you can be assured that any implementers will have defined all of its methods.  This way, you can work on a `List` reference without needing to know its exact implementation. (that is, `ArrayList`, `LinkedList`, `Vector`, etc...)

Answer (score 2):

As you say, List is an Interface, that means that you cannot initialize an interface, only with a class that implement that interface. For example ArrayList.

ArrayList implements List, its definitions is:

```
public class ArrayList implements List<E>{
 ...
}
```

You can do it like:

```
List<Mat> list = new ArrayList<Mat>();
Mat listItem ;
//code to initialize listItem properly
list.add(listItem );
```

Answer (score 1):

`List` is an interface. You need to `new` a class that implements the `List` interface. An `ArrayList` is an example:

```
List<Mat> mList = new ArrayList<Mat>();
```

Comment: Ah I see, I think... So the List is just a way of interacting with a variety of lists, such as ArrayList, so you effectively create a new ArrayList but interact with it using List?  

Is that about right? :) 

Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes. Using `List<Mat>` allows the provider of the list to select any of the classes that implements the `List` interface.

Answer (score 1):

List is an interface. You need to use an Implementation of List such as ArrayList

For example:

mList = new ArrayList()

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of a List that puts together all of your pieces:

```
// Here's a variation on your original fragment

// ArrayList is a perfectly reasonable type of List to use
private List<Mat> mList = new ArrayList<Mat>();  
private Mat listItem1;  

// (etcetera)   

mList.add(listItem1);

// And here's an example of your call to split:

Core.split(listItem1, mList);
```

Obviously, the above is a toy example based on your original question.  It should be enough to get you started, though.

With respect to the particular type of `List` to use, I generally advise people to start with `ArrayList` unless there's a real requirement to use something else.  Here's the summary from the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html):

> Resizable-array implementation of the List interface. Implements all
>   optional list operations, and permits all elements, including null. In
>   addition to implementing the List interface, this class provides
>   methods to manipulate the size of the array that is used internally to
>   store the list.

So `ArrayList` provides most of the convenience of an array within a resizable data structure that implements the `List` interface.